# How to take Password Text box in Xamarin using C# for Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I need to Take Text Box for Password for my Xamarin App using c# Mobile Application.So I have Create two Edit Text in main.xml.They Are as follows.

```
   <EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
<EditText
    android:password="true"
    android:id="@+id/txtPassword"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textVisiblePassword" />
<requestFocus />
```

and on my Activity I am using like this for Password:

```
   var editPassword = new EditText(this);
        editPassword.Id = Resource.Id.txtPassword;
```

but in the Password Text box the Text is appearing normal instead of ************.

Answer (score 6):

You should use `"IsPassword = true"` in your entry.

For example:

```
var password = new Entry { Placeholder = "Password", IsPassword = true };
```

Answer (score 2):

This [SOLUTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22254479/xamarin-c-sharp-edittext-inputtype-password) provided by @Racil Hilan, worked for me

editText.InputType = Android.Text.InputTypes.TextVariationPassword | Android.Text.InputTypes.ClassText;

I add it here to save time for others, since after reading the answers for this question (which works for me in some situations), lead me on the wrong path and wasted an hour.

Answer (score 1):

Just stumbled on the answer.

**android:inputType="textPassword"** does work with **android:hint**,

same as **android:password**. The only difference is when I use **android:gravity="center"**, the hint will not show if I'm using **android:inputType**. Case closed!

**Example:**

```
  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext_password_la"
    android:layout_below="@+id/edittext_username_la"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="15dip"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:hint="@string/string_password" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
android:inputType="textPassword"
```

instead of `android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"`(which means Text that is a password that should be visible) for `txtPassword` EditText

Comment: I have used android:inputType="textPassword" but getting the same result.