# Xamarin EditText InputType Password

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, android-edittext

I got some `EditText` fields that are created from a JSON file, so I cannot change the XML files. But I want some `EditText` fields to have input type "password". I'm working in Xamarin Studio with C#.

I got something like this but that doesn't work:

```
editText.InputType = InputTypes.TextVariationPassword;
```

Comment: When you say "but that doesn't work", what do you mean? Explain so we can help you.

Comment: The text inside the editText is just text, no ***.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this:

```
editText.InputType = Android.Text.InputTypes.TextVariationPassword | 
                          Android.Text.InputTypes.ClassText;
```

**Edit:** There are still some interest (i.e. votes) in this answer now after 2 years, so I thought of adding an explanation as requested by **Bleeding Fingers** in his comment below. I hope it will help somebody.

In many other languages/platforms (e.g. HTML), you just set your control to `password` and it works. That's what the OP was trying to do, but Android is designed differently (and quite odd IMHO). It divides the flags to **classes** and **variations**. You have to choose a class first (e.g. `ClassText`) and then apply the variations you want (e.g. `TextVariationPassword`). If you only set the variation, Android does not know what class you want. For instance, you can have a text password `TextVariationPassword` (so you combine it with the text class `ClassText`), or you can have a numeric password `NumberVariationPassword` (so you combine it with the number class `ClassNumber`).

Now all that explained starts to make some sense, except for a question somebody may ask: *Can Android not simply infer the class from the variation so we don't have to specify redundant things?* For the simple cases above it's pretty easy, but it gets more complex with several flags set to one control. Yet, I still personally think that it is relatively easily doable and better than the current redundant design that's taking many developers by surprise.

Comment: @BleedingFingers They say **better late than never**, so I added an explanation as you requested, only 2 years later :-).